# Golang replace any and all newline characters

Tags: regex, string, go

Usually, when I'm replacing newlines I jump to Regexp, like in this PHP

```
preg_replace('/\R/u', "\n", $String);
```

Because I know that to be a very durable way to replace any kind of Unicode newline (be it \n, \r, \r\n, etc.)

I was trying to something like this in Go as well, but I get

> error parsing regexp: invalid escape sequence: `\R`

On this line

```
msg = regexp.MustCompilePOSIX("\\R").ReplaceAllString(html.EscapeString(msg), "<br>\n")
```

I tried using `(?:(?>\r\n)|\v)` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389171/728236, but it looks like Go's regex implementation doesn't support that either, panicking with `invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: '(?>'`

What's a good, safe way to replace newlines in Go, Regex or not?

---

I see this answer here [Golang: Issues replacing newlines in a string from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112382/golang-issues-replacing-newlines-in-a-string-from-a-text-file) saying to use `\r?\n`, but I'm hesitant to believe that it would get *all* Unicode newlines, mainly because of this question that has answer listing many more newline codepoints than the 3 that `\r?\n` covers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: Issues replacing newlines in a string from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112382/golang-issues-replacing-newlines-in-a-string-from-a-text-file)

Comment: @ttomalak I saw that, and it's what I'm using for now, but I'm not sure if that's as all-encompassing as `\R` would be, especially because of this answer on stripping all Unicode newlines includes quite a bit more codepoints https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309489/728236

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may "decode" the `\R` pattern as

```
U+000DU+000A|[U+000AU+000BU+000CU+000DU+0085U+2028U+2029]
```

See the [Java regex docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) explaining the `\R` shorthand:

```
Linebreak matcher
\R  Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]
```

In Go, you may use the following:

```
func removeLBR(text string) string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\x{000D}\x{000A}|[\x{000A}\x{000B}\x{000C}\x{000D}\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}]`)
    return re.ReplaceAllString(text, ``)
}
```

Here is a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/5acCKHuSgDC).

Some of the Unicode codes can be replaced with regex escape sequences supported by [Go regexp](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/):

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\r\n|[\r\n\v\f\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}]`)
```

Answer (score 6):

While using regexp usually yields an elegant and compact solution, often it's not the fastest.

For tasks where you have to replace certain substrings with others, the standard library provides a really efficient solution in the form of [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer):

> Replacer replaces a list of strings with replacements. It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

You may create a reusable replacer with [`strings.NewReplacer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReplacer), where you list the pairs containing the replaceable parts and their replacements. When you want to perform a replacing, you simply call [`Replacer.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer.Replace).

Here's how it would look like:

```
const replacement = "<br>\n"

var replacer = strings.NewReplacer(
    "\r\n", replacement,
    "\r", replacement,
    "\n", replacement,
    "\v", replacement,
    "\f", replacement,
    "\u0085", replacement,
    "\u2028", replacement,
    "\u2029", replacement,
)

func replaceReplacer(s string) string {
    return replacer.Replace(s)
}
```

Here's how the regexp solution from [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594719/3832970) looks like:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\r\n|[\r\n\v\f\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}]`)

func replaceRegexp(s string) string {
    return re.ReplaceAllString(s, "<br>\n")
}
```

The implementation is actually quite fast. Here's a simple benchmark comparing it to the above pre-compiled regexp solution:

```
const input = "1st\nsecond\r\nthird\r4th\u0085fifth\u2028sixth"

func BenchmarkReplacer(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceReplacer(input)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRegexp(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceRegexp(input)
    }
}
```

And the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkReplacer-4      3000000               495 ns/op
BenchmarkRegexp-4         500000              2787 ns/op
```

For our test input, `strings.Replacer` was more than **5 times** faster.

There's also another advantage. In the example above we obtain the result as a new `string` value (in both solutions). This requires a new `string` allocation. If we need to write the result to an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) (e.g. we're creating an HTTP response or writing the result to a file), we can avoid having to create the new `string` in case of `strings.Replacer` as it has a handy [`Replacer.WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer.WriteString) method which takes an `io.Writer` and writes the result into it without allocating and returning it as a `string`. This further significantly increases the performance gain compared to the regexp solution.

Comment: That's certainly an impressive performance improvement, it looks like the other answer could be more perfect after all

Comment: @BrianLeishman If you can write the result directly into an `io.Writer`, the difference will be even bigger. See the edit at the end of the answer.